# Error Connecting to Datasource - Wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I have successfully created datasource in wildfly 8. I get an error "javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out" while trying to connect to the data source.

Can someone advise?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. Like the type of datasource you're using, the driver, etc.

Comment: Receive time out would usually mean that your app server cannot connect to database server. probably some network connectivity issue

Comment: * Post the datasource part in your standalone
* specify what DBMS you're using
I think ctomc is right, try to manually connect to database with your DBMS client to the machine which is hosting the database

Comment: three ways to create datasource in wildfly 8.2 - http://pvrworld-wildfly.blogspot.in/